# How to stop heroku dyno restart from reseting my database

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, dyno

I have a flask app on heroku.
Originally I had a free Dyno from heroku. When my website was inactive for 30 mins it would sleep, consequently reseting my database.

I then upgraded to a Hobby Dyno. This solved the issue of the dyno sleeping. Although it still has a daily restart causing my database to reset. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Try to register the blueprints after, socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

Comment: Yea i tried that. It did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you start the application with `python main.py`, then your main file should be referenced as `__main__` according to Python import rules. So in your blueprint, when you import the `socketio` object you should do it like this:

```
from __main__ import socketio
```

Comment: It underlines the line with an error. And wants me to import a Package called mksbackup.

Comment: Did you try it? I have no idea what mksbackup is, you have not discussed that in your quesiton.

Comment: I tried to install it but it said the installation failed.

Comment: I did not ask you to install anything, so I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Yes i tried : from __main__ import socketio. It gave me an error

Comment: line of code in chat.py: from __main__ import socketio               
|||| ImportError: cannot import name 'socketio' from '__main__' (/Users/path.../Sockets/main.py)

Comment: Did you move the import to the top by any chance? You had it somewhere in the middle of the blueprint file, which helps avoid circular dependencies. If you move the import to the top you will have import issues.

Comment: I have added an image to my question. it Shows the error i receive when using: from __main__ import socketio

Comment: You have to resolve the circular dependency. In main.py you are importing chat.py before `socketio` is defined, so then it is not possible to import `socketio` in chat.py because at the time this code runs `socketio` hasn't been created yet.

Comment: It still underlines the "from __ main __ import socketio" line but It works! Thank you so much !